# Creating new vectors that are annual averages from monthly vectors using a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have the following MWE:

```
list <- c("Canada","USA","Brazil","China","Germany","Spain","France","UK","India","Iran",
"Italy","Japan","Mexico","Nederlands","Norway","NZ","Philippines","Poland","Russia","Sweden","Ukraine")

#What I want to do is something like this (although this doesn't do it):
avg_Canada <- sum(Canada[1:12], Canada>0) / length(Canada[1:12, Canada>0)
   > Error in Canada[1:12, Canada > 0] : incorrect number of dimensions

#My idea for the loop
subsets <- c("1:12","13:24","25:36","37:48","49:60","61:72","73:84") #each year

for (c in seq_along(list)) {
   avg_c <- rep(1:7) #create a new vector with 7 elements for each country
   for (i in seq_along(subsets)) {
      #here go through subsets and store 7 values in each of avg_c
   }
}
```

I want to take each vector in `list` (they are `num [1:84]`) and create a new vector that takes averages of subsets of them. This is because the data contained within each is monthly and I need to convert it to annual data. Sadly I am not able to include the vectors in the MWE. When I try to create `avg_Canada` for example, I am only trying to do it for the first year as opposed to all years so I figured a loop would be appropriate to get at each year. Further, as you can tell, I have many countries.

My naming scheme is incorrect in the first nested loop, I have zero clue how to go about creating the `avg_c` variable within the second nested loop, but I believe my intuition is captured in the `avg_Canada` "attempt" if you could even call it that. Wondering if this is the way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get all the `list` countries in a list and take `mean` of every 12 elements in a list using `by`.

```
lapply(mget(list), function(x) as.numeric(by(x, rep(1:7, each  = 12), mean)))
```

This will return you a list of length `length(list)` with every element a numeric vector of size 7.

Comment: Would this go inside of the loop? Also, how would I account for the -9999 values I want to ignore? e.g. If one of the values is -9999 in one of the averages, how would I make it take the average of only 11 of the 12 values/all except for -9999?

Comment: @Brennan Using `lapply` I think is more simple I think. You can ignore -9999 value by `lapply(mget(list), function(x) as.numeric(by(x, rep(1:7, each  = 12), function(y) mean(y[y != -9999]))))`

Comment: The last argument didn't seem to work but substituting `mean(y[y > 0])` seemed to do the trick! Thank you for your efforts, I hope this is of value to someone else with a similar problem down the road

Comment: How would I save these as vectors in the environment?

Comment: you can store the output in an object `result <- lapply(mget(list), function(x)....rest of the code` and then do `list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)`